# Redirect all request internally to 3000 port apache2

Tags: node.js, apache2, web-hosting

I have a web application hosted on apache server. When I hit https://example.com then it points to the server but my application is running on 3000 port. So I want all the users to hit example.com (443 port) and internally it redirects all the request to 3000 port and make my application running.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a reverse proxy with Apache. These tutorial may help you:

- https://linuxtogether.org/configuring-reverse-proxy-for-node-using-apache-mod-proxy/
- http://garrows.com/blog/running-node-js-and-apache-together-using-mod_proxy/